# Keeping Alive a ssh session with a script bash/expect

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh, expect

Hello People i'm trying to do an script bash using a expect part to enter a server and keep alive the session, my script is as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/expect << eof
spawn ssh user@server
set prompt ":|#|\\\$"
expect "password"
interact
eof
```

I can enter to the server but the session dies after a second and return to my local computer,

Can any one help me please?

Comment: This is not the way to ssh to a server, read about ssh-keygen and ssh-agent & ssh-add

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by this script? It does just the the same thing as you would do by doing `ssh user@server`.

Comment: The last line ( `eof`) looks suspect. Remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because of HEREDOC usage. Instead you could quote the whole code as

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/expect  -c '
spawn ssh dinesh@myhost
set prompt ":|#|\\\$"
expect "password"
interact
'
```

Comment: I don't see anything amiss about that heredoc. There are no variables that the shell will substitute

Comment: @glennjackman :  The problem is happening for any limit string, not just for `EOF` or `eof`. I have tried adding debugging where I found that expect is receiving `eof`. So, I decided to go ahead with `-c` flag

Comment: @glennjackman :  I'm no bash expert and if I search in google with `expect` and `heredoc`, I used to end up with `stackoverflow` page where I see your answers only.!!! :)

Comment: I think the problem is because of `interact` command only, which used inside `heredoc` causing this issue.

Comment: Zero difference between interact in a heredoc versus in a script file.

Comment: @glennjackman : Roger that Sir!!!

Comment: Thank you @Dinesh that was the problem i put it like you said and it works correctly